# Changing Specific Formulas to apply for the whole Column

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have a Google Sheet for a gaming challenge, and I have formulas that work but am trying to automate as much as possible with array formulas, so I can add new rows as needed later.

On Copy of Main Challenge Tab, I have Column F, that largely counts 1, 2, 3, 4 etc, but sometimes I need to repeat numbers, for example 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22 etc.

In Column B, C and D, I need D to count 1-6 over and over again. Every time it’s counted to 6, Column C must increase by one, starting from 1. When Column C reaches 5, and Column D 6 once again, the next row, Column B will go from 1 to 2, and both Column D and B will start counting from 1 again (you can see this successfully implemented on the Main Challenge Tab).

I’ve got Column D working, but Column C counts up to 6, and because of the formulas used, row 40 and every 36 rows after is zero.

For Column F, I was given a formula that just automatically counts from 1 in every row going down. Realising that every row that repeats will have something written in Column Q, I tried using an IF Formula, where if Column Q was empty, I can reference another tab and count downwards, but that if something was in Column Q, Column F could be left blank, but this hasn’t worked, and it just keeps counting down. I have tried adjusting Column B, C and D, but I couldn’t get anything to work.

I am happy to share a link to my Google Sheet if that would help.

Comment: `I am happy to share a link to my Google Sheet if that would help.` Yes, that would help.

Comment: Hello! I think it's doable but plrase share a schematic sheets with desired result and we'll be able to help!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Hi everyone, I was able to get some help on another website from someone, but for those interested, I thought I’d share what was discussed and the solutions found: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3icm8PnGSysKQ5x-EZXaJgyTxOsAprdmGssVDw34GA/edit